# Python inserting to list vs dict

Tags: python

I've written code that simply reads from a database and save the results to a collection in python

I've first written in so that it was the items were stored in a dictionary, but later I realized the indexes were just incremental, so I changed it to a `list`.

However after that the speed of the program dramatically dropped. I first thought something was wrong with the MySQL database but turns out after I changed the collection to a `dict`, it came back to normal.

Code was something like:

```
cursor = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.SSDictCursor)
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM db')
coll = []  # or coll = {}
for i in cursor:
    coll.append(i)  # or coll[len(coll)] = i
```

I compared `coll.append()` and `coll[len(coll)] = i` separately and those line themselves seem to not differ that much (append was slower but not enough to cause the dramatic slowing down, which in a different orders of magnitude)

I thought the ordering might cause some issues, when I used an `OrderedDict`, the speed didn't seem to be affected.

I was wondering if it could be based on how lists and dictionaries are implemented (maybe lists has to be saved in continuous memory, thus requiring frequent reallocation of memory while dictionaries doesn't have to be continuous), but I wanted to know why this was really happening

Edit:

Here is the actual code I am running, in the case that the simplified code is missing something relevant:

```
with closing(cdr_db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.SSDictCursor)) as cdr_cursor:
    cdr_cursor.execute(query.format(TABLE_NAME))

    nID_to_num = {}  # []
    num_to_nID = {}
    g = snap.TNGraph.New()

    for call in cdr_cursor:
        from_num = call['from_num']
        to_num = call['to_num']

        if from_num == 0 or to_num == 0:
            continue

        if from_num not in num_to_nID:
            curr_index = len(nID_to_num)
            g.AddNode(curr_index)
            num_to_nID[from_num] = curr_index
            nID_to_num[curr_index] = from_num  # nID_to_num.append(from_num)
        if to_num not in num_to_nID:
            curr_index = len(nID_to_num)
            g.AddNode(curr_index)
            num_to_nID[to_num] = curr_index
            nID_to_num[curr_index] = to_num  # nID_to_num.append(to_num)

        g.AddEdge(num_to_nID[from_num], num_to_nID[to_num])
```

This is ran in Python 2.7 64bit in Windows 7.

Comment: Why not `coll = list(cursor)`?

Comment: `coll[len(coll)]` will definitely cause slowdown because the length of the list is recalculated each time. You should try using `.push()` instead of `.append()` and see if the performance is any better, I'm a bit curious myself.

Comment: I'm actually curious too. Could it be related to the fact that a list is represented as an array; the largest costs come from growing beyond the current allocation size. Which is explained here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity ? But then I'm wondering how a dictionary would grow. I guess it's also based on an array. Though if I remember correctly they grow as a linked list when collisions occur, which is less time consuming.

Comment: @DanD. that's a little simplified from the actual code, and in the real code I have to check some conditions before I actually insert to the collection, which is why simply calling list on the cursor will not work

Comment: @AlexVanLiew that I am curious about, too (I thought doing coll[len(coll)] would be inefficient compared to appending to a list) but the dictionary is way way faster than the list right now

Comment: I posted an answer ('cause all the code wouldn't fit in a comment) that, unless further code is forthcoming, the "V" in MCVE might be MIA.

Comment: @markk, what about `coll = [i for i in cursor if check_condition(i)]`?

Comment: @AlexVanLiew `len` of `dict` is O(1), so the extra increase shouldn't be as significant as what the OP is stating.

Comment: @Cyphase Is list comprehension faster than doing a for loop and appending to the list? I have two conditions and several different outcomes depending on those conditions, so that approach seemed more reasonable for me but if efficiency is at stake, I would definitely try that

Comment: @markk you say *"that's a little simplified from the actual code, and in the real code I have to check some conditions before I actually insert to the collection, which is why simply calling list on the cursor will not work"*. Your example is **too** simplified, the problem very probably lies in the other parts of your algorithm.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That might be the case, although I'm having trouble finding what I might be missing. I've edited the post to include the original code, along with the comments explaining which lines change depending on `dict` or `list`

Comment: As suspected, the real culprit is the *`in`* operation which for dictionary does *not* do what you'd want it to do; but which for list does what you want it to do, but with *O(n)* time complexity. Instead, you'd want to use a `set` to store the identifiers for fast membership checks.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you mean the statement  `if from_num not in num_to_nID`? `num_to_nID` stays a `dict` and I'm switching from `nID_to_num` being a `dict` or a `list`. And what do you mean the dictionary doesn't do what I want it to do? Is it not checking if the particular value is in the key set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update after new code posted and more back and forth between Mark and Antti:

I believe the reason why your original test case didn't show the problem is that, in your original test case, you only showed using `len()` for the dict case, where in your full example, you always use `len()`.

After playing around with timing some more, I found that if I modify the list example below to match your full example more closely, e.g. `coll.append(len(coll))` -- because you are calculating len() in both cases, then the dict case is faster.  Your original small example was incorrectly attributing the cost of len() to the dict version, even though len() is called for both versions.

However, (assuming that you are executing this code in a function, and not at script level where all lookups are costly), I found that I could recover that time *and make lists faster than dicts again* by predefining `a = coll.append` outside the loop and using that instead.

If this is the issue that you are seeing and it is that time-critical, then you will probably want to move some other lookups outside of your loop, such as the ones for `len` and `g.AddNode`.

** Original answer below **

I cannot verify your claim that dicts are faster than lists in this use-case, so perhaps you changed something else.  You didn't specify a version, so I mostly used Python 2, but used 3 to determine it was comparable in some instances.  Here is the code:

```
def usedict(times, size):
    cursor = list(range(size))
    for iteration in range(times):
        coll = {}
        for i in cursor:
            coll[len(coll)] = i


def uselist(times, size):
    cursor = list(range(size))
    for iteration in range(times):
        coll = []
        for i in cursor:
            coll.append(i)
```

And here are some results:

```
$ python -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.uselist(10, 100000)"
10 loops, best of 3: 49.7 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.usedict(10, 100000)"
10 loops, best of 3: 103 msec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.uselist(10, 100000)"
10 loops, best of 3: 65.9 msec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.usedict(10, 100000)"
10 loops, best of 3: 131 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.uselist(1, 10000000)"
10 loops, best of 3: 666 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.usedict(1, 10000000)"
10 loops, best of 3: 3.66 sec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.uselist(100000, 10)"
10 loops, best of 3: 69.6 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.usedict(100000, 10)"
10 loops, best of 3: 82.1 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.uselist(100000, 4)"
10 loops, best of 3: 29.4 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.usedict(100000, 4)"
10 loops, best of 3: 34.4 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.uselist(1000000, 1)"
10 loops, best of 3: 151 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.usedict(1000000, 1)"
10 loops, best of 3: 148 msec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.uselist(1000000, 1)"
10 loops, best of 3: 177 msec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.usedict(1000000, 1)"
10 loops, best of 3: 213 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.uselist(1000000, 3)"
10 loops, best of 3: 245 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "import listdict;listdict.usedict(1000000, 3)"
10 loops, best of 3: 272 msec per loop
```

For larger containers, lists were a clear winner -- 5 times faster with 10e6 items.  The only place where dicts came out ahead was Python 2.7 with a single entry per container, and that was by a trivial amount.

This was on a 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04 system.

Comment: This seems expected to me. Both `list.append` and `dict.__setitem__` are O(1), and time loss for underlying array resizing should affect both data structures in roughly the same way. Additionally, you perform an extra O(1) operation on every iteration in `usedict`, namely `len(coll)`, so really that interior loop will be about O(2*n) whereas the list version will just be O(n), where n is the size of `cursor`. You could change it to `coll[i] = i` just to see if that removes some of the gap.

Comment: The example uses the exact code the the OP shows.  I'm not interested in optimizing it -- I'm interested in showing that the question requires some work to make it a MVCE.

Comment: Sure, that's fine. I'm not interested in that. I'm interested in understanding how the observed output in your post relates to the code. It should be connected to the known running time complexity of each algorithm, which is borne out in your code, but not in the OP's original claim.

Comment: And then maybe I could use `append = col.append` to open the gap back up again :-)  But seriously, I agree with you that my results were expected, and that they could be tweaked a bit one way or another.  I'm not interested in micro-optimizations atm -- the OP's claim was "dramatic slowing down."  But feel free to edit my answer to add more test runs :-)  (I have a feeling that when the smoke clears the question and answer will both be gone.)

Comment: @PatrickMaupin Yeah.. this is similar to what I got when I tested it before asking this question. The code I have is the gist of it except for checking the conditions which are pretty trivial. I was using Python 2.7 64 bit btw. I've run this both by simply commenting in and out the lines and the list case doesn't end even after an hour while the dictionary case ends in 3 minutes.